# How do programmatically turn ON blackberry's internal GPS?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, gps

Does anyone know how to programmatically turn on the Blackberry internal GPS receiver?
Curve 9230

Answer (score 1):

LocationInfo.setLocationOn()?

Check the API documentation for restrictions.

Comment: Doesn't works ,and i signed the project and it doesn't turn on             my emulated BB gps

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/gps/LocationInfo.html#setLocationOn()). As Peter said, there are also IT policies and service books in consideration when you call that method.

Comment: "development on BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators can occur without code signing." and i use on a simulator/emulator and it doesn't turn on GPS